# String cannot be converted to JSONObject for a registration page

Tags: java, php, android, json

i am trying to make a registration page, and i have completed the xml page and i have written the activity java file
here is the code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    final EditText etUserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserEmail);
    final EditText etUserContactNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserContactNo);
    final EditText etUserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserPassword);
    final Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String UserName = etUserName.getText().toString();
            final String UserContactNo = etUserContactNo.getText().toString();
            final String UserEmail = etUserEmail.getText().toString();
            final String UserPassword = etUserPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success =  jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success){
                            Intent intent  = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Registration Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(UserName, UserPassword, UserContactNo, UserEmail, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);

        }
    });

}
```

}

and the php file that is connected to the activity

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("******", "*****", "*******", "*******");

$UserName = $_POST["UserName"];
$UserPassword = $_POST["UserPassword"];
$UserContactNo = $_POST["UserContactNo"];
$UserEmail = $_POST["UserEmail"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO UserDetails (UserName,UserContactNo, UserEmail, UserPassword) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $UserName, $UserContactNo, $UserEmail, $UserPassword);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

and the problem that i am facing, which is written in the android monitor

```
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.hp.myapplication.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:43)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.hp.myapplication.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:39)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-30 20:36:22.928 2828-2828/com.example.hp.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-30 20:39:24.125 1582-1595/system_process I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
```

Comment: `<br` tends to suggest you're receiving HTML. Have you tested out your PHP script via a web browser or REST tool to check if you're receiving the JSON you expect?

Comment: now i am not getting a html error i fixed the php file
the error i am getting now is
org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: and regarding the output of php file i am getting this Connected successfully{"success":true}

Comment: Can you update the logcat with the new crash log? Maybe log the value of `response`?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your backend part: your php script should return json content with next header: `Content-Type:application/json;`. Now it returns `text/html`.

Comment: the html thing is not fixed

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: this is the issue that i am facing now

Answer (score 0):

Add this header in your php, that´s the way to return only json without html

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Now your php sholud look like this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("******", "*****", "*******", "*******");

$UserName = $_POST["UserName"];
$UserPassword = $_POST["UserPassword"];
$UserContactNo = $_POST["UserContactNo"];
$UserEmail = $_POST["UserEmail"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO UserDetails (UserName,UserContactNo, UserEmail, UserPassword) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $UserName, $UserContactNo, $UserEmail, $UserPassword);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response->success= true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I add the code in my answer, you return an array, you should change it and return an object, if you dont want change the array in android first parse in JSONArray and after that parse the JSONObject `success`